# Using "hash" in function defs, and in variable assignments

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, hash, network-programming

I am new to Ruby

I have found the code below which I want to understand.

1) I understand that the 1st `hash` in the initialise function is a parameter. Is `hash` here also an Associative array?

2) The second hash in `hash['FILENAME']` - is this using the parameter in the function def, or is it defining a new hash (ie associative array)?

3) I presume `self.myfilename` is set to an array with element value of `'FILENAME'` ?

4) Why have the `|| ""` ?

```
require 'rex/socket'
require 'rex/proto/dhcp'
module Rex
module Proto
module DHCP

Class Server
include Rex::Socket
def initialise(hash, context={})
...
self.myfilename = hash['FILENAME'] || ""
...
```

Comment: The first `hash` is in the definition of a function—as such, it's not specified what it is, it's just a placeholder. The second one assumes that an associative array named `hash` exists. If the line in the second part is inside the function definition, then yes, it'll be using the parameter from the function definition. The double bar means ‘or’, so if the parameter passed to the function when it is run isn't an associative array that contains an element `FILENAME`, then `self.myfilename` will be set to the alternative option, which is `""` (i.e., an empty string).

Comment: Terminology note: "Associative array" is a term you'll find in very few programming languages, including Ruby. (The only mainstream exception I know of is PHP.) It's an unfortunate term because it makes newcomers mistake hashes for a special kind of array, which they are not. Ruby has Arrays and Hashes, and it will serve you to think of them as entirely different things, because they are. The only thing they have in common is that you can use square brackets (i.e. a method named `#[]`) to access the elements of both.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes, `hash` should be an Associative Array - similar to Dictionary in python or HashMap in Java. `hash` should be a variable of type `Hash`. Given this much the information one can't definitively say that `hash` is of type `Hash`, but the name of the variable and seeing how it's accessed `Hash["FILENAME"]` gives a strong clue that it should be a `Hash`.

(2) It is using the parameter passed in the initialize method. Not defining new a new `Hash`.

(3) `self.myfilename` is set to 'value' corresponding to 'key': 'FILENAME' in the `hash`.

(4) `a = b || ""` in ruby means that a is assigned the value of b, but if b is `nil` then it is set "" (empty string). Hence, in the above code, `|| ""` is added to make sure that if hash doesn't have a key 'FILENAME' then `self.filename` is assigned empty string rather than `nil`.

Hope it helps : )

Comment: I've never actually used Ruby, but is the `hash` parameter in the function definition not simply non-cast? How can you tell it’s of type `Hash` in #1?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're correct. The above code requires only that the object referenced by `hash` has a `#[]` method that accepts a String argument. Despite the name, which gives us a clue as to how it's going to be used, it needn't be a Hash.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're correct. It need not be a Hash for sure. But from the variable name `hash` and seeing how it is accessed `hash["FILENAME"]` it gives a very strong clue that it should be a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ruby!
1) You are right here. `context` has default value of `{}`.
2) It uses `hash` parameter given to function and takes it's `FILENAME` key.
3) `self.myfilename` is equal to the value of `FILENAME` key of `hash` variable.
4) If hash does not contain key it will return `nil`. So here `|| ""` sets `self.myfilename` to empty string and not `nil`.

Comment: so for example say I called the function initialise, with `initialise(test.txt,"")` - would `self.myfilename` become `hash['test.txt'] || "" ` then stored as `text.txt` ?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it is rather strange situation. I do not see the reason to pass string and then call `['test.txt']` on it.